# Trace javascript request to its original code

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a huge javascript code that sends POST and GET requests to an API using jQuery, I'm interested in a specific POST request that I want to trace its response but couldn't find the code responsible for it since the request was dynamically generated.

Is there a plugin or a method that allows me to find the code line/section that sent a specific request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any request, there is request URL. If the request send from only one file then get the request url from chrome browser by pressing `F12` and then go to `Network` tab which shows all request url send from that page from browser. If you Network tab is empty then open network tab as it is and refresh page by pressing `F5` and view all request. Click on url you are interested which shows new options. Select Headers if not selected and then copy whole `Request URL` and search in file else select some part or url and then search.

Answer (score 0):

if you run your code on a browser.
there are plenty of ways to monitor all requests going out of your browser.
just search for 
chrome developer toolbar(a built-in tool in chrome browser) or firefox developer tool(built-in tool on firefox, shortcut key is ctrl+shift+q) or firebug a third party plugin for firefox(most powerful in my opinion)

just go to the network tab(all three of these have similar structure, and have a network tab).
there you can monitor the requests getting out of your browser.

in firebug(that I use for myself) you can filter request by they return type and etc. and you can easily see their request headers, response , cache and cookies.